# How to sum/process portions of a pivot table results?

Tags: pivot-table, libreoffice-calc

Having a personal spreadsheet document to capture solved tasks (date, customer, project, detail, from time, to time --> consumed hours), I am already using the pivot table on another sheet to group spent hours for each day (independently on customers, project id, details). The result looks like this:

[image: Current content]

The column A contains the date, the column B shows Sum - hours (1). Notice also total sum at the bottom, marked as (5). I have added the C (2) as working over 8 hours (green) or under 8 hours (pink). The D (3) flags Saturdays (here "sobota") and Sundays. The E is like C but showing only values for working days.

Just now, I add the extra field to sum the values for one month, in the red rectangle:

[image: Summary for month in the red rectangle]

The problem is that I have to check the ranges (rows) that are being summed. Also, I have to make the correction for summing also the "Total" (5).

The number of days in the source pivot is never fixed. This is because some days are not recorded. So, not every day is listed. Also, the leap year has one extra day.

I was thinking first about automatic detection of days (rows) for each month; so, each of the red rectangles for the month could determine the source range. Later, the following question came to my mind...

Can another pivot on the sheet be used to calculate the "red-rectangle values"?

What would be your approach/recommendation to solve the problem?

Comment: What about `{=SUMIF(MONTH(A2:A63);ROW(A1:A12);B2:B63)}`?

Comment: @JohnSUN: If I understand you, I could move the block in red to the line where the month begins (this is fine), and make the range rather long. Then only the month data will be summed. Correct?

Comment: No, the idea is different. The SUMIF() and SUMIFS() functions allow you to sum data from an entire column conditionally - exactly what you are asking for. The hardest part is describing the condition. In this case, I propose to apply the MONTH() function to the entire date column, so that we do not deal with the entire date, but only with the month number. Now we apply this condition sequentially to the first month (January), the second (February) and so on. This will make the array {1|2}3....)It remains to indicate that we want to sum the numbers from column B (or, if you wish, from column E)

Comment: @JohnSUN: I see. Please, copy the solution as the answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: Actually my comments are not a real solution or answer to the question about parts of the PivotTable results. You can apply the same SUMIF() or SUMMES() functions directly to the source data, without using a PivotTable. Or select a date field, press F12 and set the grouping by month. There are many possible solutions, but they do not answer the question in the title of the topic, this will not help those who will look for a solution in the future.